# Upgrade Python from 2.6 to higher version

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, python-2.6

I am using ArcGIS 10 desktop version. With this, the installed Python is 2.6. For some raster functionality (GDAL) I have to install the wheel file, to install wheel file I have to pip before to this. Now I am getting error as pip is not supporting Python 2.6 version.

Is there any way I can upgrade this Python version to install pip?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. ArcGIS 10.0 has been retired from service for several years. You will find it difficult to find others using the same ancient software here, which will present a challenge in getting help.  I'd  recommend using more recent software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you won't want to do that. It will affect the stability of the ArcGIS Geoprocessing engine. ESRI builds/packages the Python version and dependencies. When you try to replace/upgrade this you will find instabilities as well as entering a unsupported platform by them if you needed support.

Answer (score 3):

I feel like this question warrants a little more explanation than the [currently accepted answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/267745/115).

Each version of ArcGIS is built against a particular version of Python. You can see that list here: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000013224

The statement you can't change the version of Python is generally true. You can (generally) upgrade a DOT-DOT (bug fix/patch) release of Python and it'll continue to work.

For example, this is what 10.2 supports per the article:

`10.2 - Python 2.7.3 and Numerical Python 1.6.1`

You should be able to upgrade Python to `2.7.5` without any issue. But as mentioned, I don't believe this is officially supported. Anyways, this **does not** answer your question on PIP. Instead of looking to figure out how to upgrade Python, try looking at installing PIP.

Per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows , Pip is now included with Python at 2.7.9 and 3.4. (This doesn't help you). What does help are the instructions there that explain how you can download and install PIP. Once you got PIP installed, try installing your GDAL wheel again.